# How to redirect HTTP request to different local web servers

Tags: webserver, http

I have a Linux machine and some applications are running web interfaces.

I'd like to create a web server, opened to the Internet, in order to access these local web interfaces (or web interface on others local machines).

Example, from the Internet:

```
http(s)://mywebserver/webmin  --> redirects to localhost:10000  (webmin interface)
http(s)://mywebserver/bitt   --> redirects to localhost:1234  (bittorrent client interface)
http(s)://mywebserver/httpd   --> redirects to localhost:88  (mini http server)
http(s)://mywebserver/ddwrt  --> redirects to 192.168.0.254:80  (dd-wrt interface)
```

etc...

Do you know a way to do this? I tried "pound" reverse proxy, but it doesn't work.

Comment: why is it not ok ? Your answer really is a reverse proxy. what's wrong with what you have.

Comment: i configured pound, same as slm's answer, and the problem is that the "transfered" http request contains the wrong parameter, i mean:

http(s)://mywebserver/bitt  sends "GET /bitt" http request to the bittorrent client, which is not able to process this, so a get a blank page, a "GET /" request is necessary.
Same problem with ddwrt or webmin.

I would need pound to put "GET /" requests, instead of "GET /XXX"

Comment: Pound is designed to be clean lean and fast, so URL re-writing isn't provided. nginex could do that, however couldn't you add the alias to the target webserver ie `/bitt => /`

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely looking for a reverse proxy and Pound can do exactly what you want. So can a whole host of other reverse proxy technologies such as Varnish, Nginx, Apache, HAProxy, and others. To understand the difference take a look at this SO Q&A titled: [Difference between proxy server and reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server).

Here's an example Pound configuration which should give you a rough idea of what you're looking for, from the article titled: [Pound secure reverse proxy "how to"](https://calomel.org/pound.html). There's also another good example here, titled: [Pound - Reverse Proxy Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pound).

```
ListenHTTP
  Address 192.168.1.5
  Port    80

    Service
      URL "/webmin"
      BackEnd
        Address localhost
        Port    10000
      End
    End

    Service
      URL "/bitt"
      BackEnd
        Address localhost
        Port    1234
      End
    End

End
..
...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried this, but the problem is:

http(s)://mywebserver/bitt sends "GET /bitt" http request to the bittorrent client, which is not able to process it, so a get a blank page, a "GET /" request is necessary.

Comment: @Matt - ah, HTTPS is a different animal. Check this tutorial for an example of HTTPS: http://perfectlylogical.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/pound_reverse_ssl_proxy_for_mutliple_servers/. I don't have time to write it up now, lmk if it works and I'll add it to this A later tonight.